# Получить всё что находится между двумя строками на python

Tags: python, строки

Есть такой текст:

```
Start
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
...
Line N
End
```

Вопрос: Как мне получить всё что между "Start" и "End", **с учетом что между ними может быть абсолютно любой текст, с разными отступами**.

Comment: А как вы уже пытались это решить? И в абсолютно любой текст `start` и `end` могут входить?

Comment: `"\n".join(text.split("\n")[1:-1])`

Comment: между строками "Start" и "End" может входить любой текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = "Start\nLine 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5\n...\nLine N\nEnd"
start = 'Start'
end = 'End'
pattern = text[text.find(start)+len(start):text.rfind(end)]
```